# How to avoid the button 's border in android webbrowser?

Tags: android, html, web

Now i have met a issue is that i built a mobile website,i use a tag "" as a button , then add a click method ,but in my android webbrowser,i could see a border in yellow , such as this

the screenshot picture at here,
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSeZl.png,
I try to use this code to fix

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

but it isn't work.
I want to know how to avoid it. this is the first time i ask question in stackoverflow.my english is not good. i didn't know wheather you understand. thank you.

Comment: Have you checked on phone, may be that is showing what is selected currently. On touch base phone you won't even notice b'cause this border will apear onclick only, so that won't be trouble for you.

Comment: yes, when i select the button,the border is visible,but i think it is ugly. and i see the other website such as m.baidu.com(the bigest search engine) don't have the border(their code had encryption ).i want to know how to fix it.

Comment: hmm, why do you think its ugly..  ok please [check out this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).. in here read, the **Touch Mode** section. And yes, please check on real device and then tell if that's really a concern

Answer (score 0):

Don't use button, the device may have some sort of logic for buttons that do that yellow thing. Try using images instead and listen to they click event.